# Which processor do I specify when I load HCS08 firmware to IDA?

Tags: ida, firmware

> Motorola/Freescale MC680xx, CPU32 (68330), MC6301, MC6303, MC6800,
> MC6801, MC6803, MC6805, MC6808, HCS08, MC6809, MC6811, M68H12C,
> ColdFire

IDA claims to have the support for HCS08. But I can't see it in the list of the processors:
[image]

Should I use 6808? Or maybe HCS12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it’s under “Freescale”

Comment: Ahh. True. It's called Freescale HSC08